# Error after install of tensor flow 1.5 (linux mint 18.3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, linux-mint

Just finished the installation of tensor flow (gpu enable) 1.5 On a Clevo laptop, under linux mint 18.3 with nvidia 1060 gpu and when running the test program python premade_estimator.py I get the following error code :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "premade_estimator.py", line 20, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/empereur/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/empereur/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/empereur/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/empereur/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/empereur/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/empereur/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have installed the cuda driver 9.0 as showed by that :

```
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
```

I look at the forum, and most of the problem where either conflict between two version (not my case) or the path to version 9.0 not done (which i think I did)

I am a bit newbie to this so help would be much much appreciated

If any information is missing, just ask and I will give the info (but please, I am a newbie, so let me know how to get the info with the command line)

here are the content of usr/local/

> empereur@empereur-Sky-X4C ~ $ ls /usr/local/ bin      cuda
>   cuda-9.1  games    lib  sbin   src Brother  cuda-9.0  etc
>   include  man  share

here are the content of usr/local/cuda/lib64 libaccinj64.so

> empereur@empereur-Sky-X4C ~ $ ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64 libaccinj64.so 
>   libcusparse.so.9.1.85  libnppist.so.9.1.85 libaccinj64.so.9.1
>   libcusparse_static.a   libnppist_static.a libaccinj64.so.9.1.85 
>   libnppc.so             libnppisu.so libcublas_device.a
>   libnppc.so.9.1         libnppisu.so.9.1 libcublas.so
>   libnppc.so.9.1.85      libnppisu.so.9.1.85 libcublas.so.9.1
>   libnppc_static.a       libnppisu_static.a libcublas.so.9.1.128
>   libnppial.so           libnppitc.so libcublas.so.9.1.85
>   libnppial.so.9.1       libnppitc.so.9.1 libcublas_static.a
>   libnppial.so.9.1.85    libnppitc.so.9.1.85 libcudadevrt.a
>   libnppial_static.a     libnppitc_static.a libcudart.so
>   libnppicc.so           libnpps.so libcudart.so.9.1
>   libnppicc.so.9.1       libnpps.so.9.1 libcudart.so.9.1.85
>   libnppicc.so.9.1.85    libnpps.so.9.1.85 libcudart_static.a
>   libnppicc_static.a     libnpps_static.a libcufft.so
>   libnppicom.so          libnvblas.so libcufft.so.9.1
>   libnppicom.so.9.1      libnvblas.so.9.1 libcufft.so.9.1.85
>   libnppicom.so.9.1.85   libnvblas.so.9.1.128 libcufft_static.a
>   libnppicom_static.a    libnvblas.so.9.1.85 libcufftw.so
>   libnppidei.so          libnvgraph.so libcufftw.so.9.1
>   libnppidei.so.9.1      libnvgraph.so.9.1 libcufftw.so.9.1.85
>   libnppidei.so.9.1.85   libnvgraph.so.9.1.85 libcufftw_static.a
>   libnppidei_static.a    libnvgraph_static.a libcuinj64.so
>   libnppif.so            libnvrtc-builtins.so libcuinj64.so.9.1
>   libnppif.so.9.1        libnvrtc-builtins.so.9.1 libcuinj64.so.9.1.85
>   libnppif.so.9.1.85     libnvrtc-builtins.so.9.1.85 libculibos.a
>   libnppif_static.a      libnvrtc.so libcurand.so           libnppig.so 
>   libnvrtc.so.9.1 libcurand.so.9.1       libnppig.so.9.1
>   libnvrtc.so.9.1.85 libcurand.so.9.1.85    libnppig.so.9.1.85
>   libnvToolsExt.so libcurand_static.a     libnppig_static.a
>   libnvToolsExt.so.1 libcusolver.so         libnppim.so
>   libnvToolsExt.so.1.0.0 libcusolver.so.9.1     libnppim.so.9.1
>   libOpenCL.so libcusolver.so.9.1.85  libnppim.so.9.1.85
>   libOpenCL.so.1 libcusolver_static.a   libnppim_static.a
>   libOpenCL.so.1.0 libcusparse.so         libnppist.so
>   libOpenCL.so.1.0.0 libcusparse.so.9.1     libnppist.so.9.1       stubs

Comment: Probably the problem is that, you have not installed `CuDNN`, which is a neural network helper library for CUDA. Please post the contents of `/usr/local/` and `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` directory.

Comment: I posted the ouput at the end of my question. I did install CuDNN and run the test program (giving a long output but ending with test succefull) I am suprised to see I seem to have 9.1 installed to.... (i really thaught i did not install it!) might it be the problem?

Comment: Hum... I think that when in install the nvidia cuda toolkit, I did not specify the version (so it install 9.1 and install cuda 9.1 as a dependency...) I am currently trying to purge cuda 9.1... hope it will work (without breaking anything!)

Comment: You are right about the problem. But instead of purging `9.1`, you can point the cuda symlink to point to `CUDA-9.0` or update the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `bashrc` to point to `CUDA-9.0`

Comment: Well, it is purged now, and tensorflow is working! Not a clean installation (I can't run nvcc --version : it's telling me to install cuda-toolkit (witch i alredy have) so i guess i can expect a few probleme on the long run, but for now it will do! thanks all for your advice, really apreciated!

Comment: hum... is there a way to say the problem is solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for the help, so i accidentaly installed cuda 9.1 (9.0 is needed). I did that while not specificly forcing the version on cuda-toolkits. Solved my problem (improperly) by purging cuda 9.1 and nvidia-cuda-toolkit and reinstalling the 9.0 version. Could probably have solve it a more clean way by following the suggestion of laylog

> But instead of purging 9.1, you can point the cuda symlink to point to
>   CUDA-9.0 or update the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your bashrc to point to
>   CUDA-9.0

Thanks again all!